# JVM: Invalid index 1 in LocalVariableTable

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to compile the following code using a custom compiler:

```
public static void main([String] args)
{
    long i = 2L
    i *= 2L
    System out println i
}
```

The result of the compilation is, when using `javap`, this Bytecode:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: ldc2_w        #14                 // long 2l
         3: lstore_1      
         4: lload_1       
         5: ldc2_w        #14                 // long 2l
         8: lmul          
         9: lstore_1      
        10: getstatic     #21                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        13: lload_1       
        14: invokevirtual #27                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(J)V
        17: return        
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      17     1     i   J
            0      17     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
    MethodParameters:
      Name                           Flags
      args
```

However, when I try to run the Bytecode, the JVM throws a `ClassFormatError` that reads `Invalid index 1 in LocalVariableTable`. Is this related to the fact that in the LocalVariableTable, slot 1 comes before slot 0?

***EDIT***:

If I change the `long` variable to an `int`, the JVM does not complain at all, even if the LocalVariableTable is still unsorted:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: iconst_2      
         1: istore_1      
         2: iload_1       
         3: iconst_2      
         4: imul          
         5: istore_1      
         6: getstatic     #19                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         9: iload_1       
        10: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
        13: return        
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      13     1     i   I
            0      13     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
    MethodParameters:
      Name                           Flags
      args
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have found the answer myself:

Since `i` is a `long`, it needs two slots to be stored. However, it is still ok to put it in the LocalVariableTable once, as long as you count it twice when calculating the max locals.

That means the code works if the bytecode looks like this (`locals=3`):

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=5, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: ldc2_w        #14                 // long 2l
         3: lstore_1      
         4: lload_1       
         5: ldc2_w        #14                 // long 2l
         8: lmul          
         9: lstore_1      
        10: getstatic     #21                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        13: lload_1       
        14: invokevirtual #27                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(J)V
        17: return        
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      17     1     i   J
            0      17     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
    MethodParameters:
      Name                           Flags
      args
```

Comment: The `LocalVariableTable` is just for debugging, you can omit it if you don’t need it. Btw. if you don’t need the `args` parameter, you can store the `long` into index `0` as well, re-using the stack frame place. Then you only need 2 `locals` (not that you need *any* local variable in this code). Another side note, if you want to push the `long` constant `2L`, it’s more efficient to use `iconst_2` followed by `i2l`, this takes 2 bytes while `ldc2_w` requires three bytes *plus* a dedicated constant pool entry…

Comment: More efficient as in *smaller bytecode* or *faster execution*?

Comment: Since the execution is implementation-specific/unpredictable and JIT/optimizers will be able do handle both equally, it’s only the byte code size that matters, but the code size has an obvious impact on the loading /initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not an answer (cannot comment this.. :P)

Your custom compiler is going wrong somewhere..

```
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      17     1     i   J
        0      17     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
```

You can't have the same start index for 2 local variables.

java compiler gives you :

```
 Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
     0      18     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
     4      14     1     i   J
```

Comment: If I change `long` to `int` and don't change the sorting of the LVT, the JVM doesn't complain anymore (see my Edit).

Comment: @Clashsoft - I still see a problem with your local variable table..  2 variables can't start at the same index :P

Comment: Yes they can, because parameters always start at index 0.